# From Postgres CDC to BigQuery with materialized views

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, gcloud, debezium, cdc

I'm designing a Change Data Capture from our Postgres to BigQuery.

I came across something that seems a powerful combination of:

- Google BigQuery sync connector: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-bigquery/current/overview.html
- BigQuery Materialized Views: [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#:~:text=Each%20base%20table%20can%20be,rewrite%20(or%20smart%20tuning)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#:%7E:text=Each%20base%20table%20can%20be,rewrite%20(or%20smart%20tuning)).

My intuition tells me that by combining these two features, I should be able to have always up to date, incremental synced tables, with the least amount of engineering.

However, the lack of documentation (or suggesting different approaches) from the Google documentation, makes me skeptical that the above approach would work:
e.g. from google docs:

- This seems a good approach, but falls short on "why materialized don't work" and just names a scheduled merge job:
  https://cloud.google.com/architecture/database-replication-to-bigquery-using-change-data-capture
- this falls short of the compaction of changes (https://cloud.google.com/architecture/capturing-change-logs-with-debezium)

So yes, the idea would be having a materialized view such as

```
given a table composed by the columns (id, version, json_valeus, soft_delete)

CREATE Materialized view SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE concat(id, version) in (SELECT concat(id, max(version)) FROM myTable GROUP BY id)
```

Would this be extremely inefficient/not work?

System size:

- about 1000 tables,
- with 1M to 500M rows each.
- 10-50M updates/day total across all tables

Expected cost:

- 5-15k/month

Comment: I've see it got a -1. Could you please add some direction so I can improve the question?
Unfortunately many of the GCloud questions are not tasks that can have a simple answer, but I found extremely valuable the answers I find on SO on these topics. I hope this can help many other engineers

Comment: Your question is more on the design and architecture to implement your requirement, which is not suitable for Stack Overflow. Please ask this question in the [Software Engineering Stack Forum](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I personally consider this question also falling under the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is" and "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" since it is very specific to the use of `Materialized Views` in BigQuery. The goal of the question is not about designing a CDC system and listing generic components. I added some details about system inputs since I wanted to clarify on the scale and verify that BigQuery is the right tool. I appreciate any feedback

Comment: Hi @M4rk, as per this [meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8965), "Will my approach work?" type questions are on-topic for software engineering provided there is enough information in the question (which you have clearly specified). So, I thought it was worth asking the question there.

Comment: If your concern is about the availability of documentation from Google Cloud, could you please post your question in the [Cloud Community forum](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Google-Cloud/ct-p/google-cloud). This community hosts peer-to-peer product forums and is a great resource to get answers.

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj the question seems well put and it is about a well scoped feature technology. Posting in underutilized forums is not the solution. So please, abstain from redirecting to other websites disincentivizing people using SO. I'm fairly certain that many questions you have answered/asked as well could fit under a broad definition of "Will my approach work". Thank you for your advice

Comment: This is a cool approach for real time replication but impossible as far as I understand with materialized views, the documentation states you cannot filter based on aggregated values, your view does that when checking if the id, version pair is in the subquery which uses groupby